# Spring Security grails plugin fails when deployed as war tomcat 6

Tags: grails, spring-security, tomcat6, war

I've seen a similar question asked with the exact same error as I have, however the context was different. I am not having problems with testing, rather, user and role creation fail completely on launch.

When using the spring-security-core 1.2.7 plugin with grails 1.3.7 and tomcat 6, I get this failure:

2012-01-04 16:23:12,476 [main] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: setTest.Role.save() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[flush:true]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), sleep(long), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:87)
...

The app runs fine when launched with grails runApp, but upon war'ing, it fails to deploy every time. The error seems to center around my user account/role creation in the bootstrap:

```
def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)
def testUser = new User(username: 'me', enabled: true, password: 'password')
testUser.save(flush: true)
UserRole.create testUser, adminRole, true
```

This is taken from the springSecurity tutorial directly. Any suggestions?

Edit: Additionally, this also fails with grails prod run-war and it is directly related to role/user creation. Even with different names for users and roles, the problem persists.

Edit 2: Also, the failure is on the .save(), which of course the original error message showed. I verified that a regular .save() vs a save(flush: true) makes no difference.

Edit 3: It seems it might be a bug in the current version of plugin: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-152
I'll keep you guys posted!

Edit 4: Confirmed, reverting to version 1.2.6 seems to fix the issue!

Comment: If you uninstall the plugin and run `grails clean` and redeploy, does it still fail? The domain classes will still work since they're not coupled to the plugin (except the password encoding stuff in the user class, you'll need to comment that out). I'm trying to see if it's really a plugin issue or if that's a red herring.

Comment: Yeah, this is 100% reproducible in any clean project. Make a clean grails app, install spring security core, add a group or user into the bootstrap, make sure you call save() on that user/group to persist it, then try grails prod runWar. Or grails war and do a deploy to app server. Still happens

Comment: Sorry, I mean does it fail without the plugin installed. I can't see how the plugin would affect GORM in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the current version of plugin: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-152

I reverted to 1.2.6 and have no issues at all. Hope this is helpful to someone else (I know I lost 2 hours to this)!

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the command *s2-quickstart* ?

Is *Config.groovy* set up correctly?

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName="....User"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName="....UserRole"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className="....Role"
```

Comment: Yep, everything is default, and like I said, it does work with a simple grails runApp, it's grails prod run-war that fails